# Adding new node and its child nodes to XML document using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, appendchild, clonenode

This is a sample of my XML document which shows a website sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Esurance 365 Portal">
    <elements>
        <element name="folderone" path="forms/folderone">
            <folder function="model">models</folder>
            <folder function="controller">controllers</folder>
            <folder function="view">views</folder>
        </element>
    </elements>
</project>
```

I would like to use `DOMDocument` to add another element node above the one illustrated so that it appears as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="Esurance 365 Portal">
        <elements>
           <element name="foldertwo" path="forms/foldertwo">
                <folder function="model">modelstwo</folder>
                <folder function="controller">controllerstwo</folder>
                <folder function="view">viewstwo</folder>
            </element>
            <element name="folderone" path="forms/folderone">
                <folder function="model">models</folder>
                <folder function="controller">controllers</folder>
                <folder function="view">views</folder>
            </element>
        </elements>
    </project>
```

But from the `DOMDocument` documentation I cant seem to find even an example that shows me how the new element would be achieved.

The `createElement` and `appendChild` methods only show me how to insert the element node but not how to insert the remaining folder child nodes.

Comment: using these functions you should get back a new DOM Node/Element on that you can call appendChild again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `element` tag and use [`cloneNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php) to copying it. Using [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) set new value of attribute and using `nodeValue` set new text in target tag. At the end of code, insert new element before existing element using [`insertBefore()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
// select "element" tag and copy it
$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName("element")->item(0);
$clone = $element->cloneNode(true);
// change value of attribute 
$clone->setAttribute("name", "foldertwo");
$clone->setAttribute("path", "forms/foldertwo");
// select "folder" tag in new "element" tag change text of them
$folder = $clone->getElementsByTagName("folder");
$folder->item(0)->nodeValue = "modelstwo";
$folder->item(1)->nodeValue = "controllerstwo";
$folder->item(2)->nodeValue = "viewstwo";
// insert new elements before existing element.
$element->parentNode->insertBefore($clone, $element);
$xml = $dom->saveXml();
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/TlQso)

Comment: It does the trick ;-) but I would have also liked to get one which can create the node directly without having to clone an existing one.